# Class name and package name in manifest file

Tags: java, jar

I converted java project into a jar file. I am able to see package name and class name in manifest file in eclipse. But, if I make a jar file of the project and extract and see the manifest file, then it doesn't have class name and package name. Can someone help me on this???

Comment: What are you using to create the JAR? Why do you need the manifest file? You want to make the JAR executable?

Comment: Yeah I would like to execute the program through command prompt using jar file.

Comment: Not very clear info, can you some details. I mean what exactly have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using Eclipse you can follow instructions [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-37.htm). You can also do it manually but in most cases it's not practical.